# I remove a StackExchange OpenID login but it still links to my account

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, login, openid

Due to change of email address, I removed my StackExchange OpenID login and added a new one instead with the new email address.

However, if I go to another machine, delete all cookies and cache, so that stack exchange doesn't recognize me, and log-in using my old StackExchange OpenID, it automatically gets added to my account!

I'm trying to get rid of the old one altogether.

1. Is there a way to delete the old StackExchange OpenID altogether? That email and password should no longer be able to log-in anywhere.
2. Isn't it plain wrong that I remove a log-in from my account yet still when someone logs in using that login they are automatically added back to my account? I specifically asked to remove that log-in and apparently it did nothing since logging in to it would result in the same account...

Edit: Just making sure I'm clear - I did have to log in (enter email and password again), it didn't keep me logged in, but when I used the old OpenID credentials, that are no longer attached to this account, I still reached this account and was able to make changes to it.

Comment: Did you use the log out button on another machine first?

Comment: @Manishearth: The other machine was never logged-in in the first place, but just in case I cleared all cache and cookies as well.

Comment: hm. I've messed with openid before, it never troubled me...

Comment: Did you change the email address value in your profile?

Comment: @Tim Stone: I did.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I just too removed an old email and it works for me (old email no longer linked to my account)