# Removing an old email address login entirely

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, email-addresses

When I first signed up for StackExchange, I used a disposable email address to create an account since I didn't think I'd be using the account more than once. However, that changed (which I guess points to the strength of StackExchange).

I wasn't bothered about retaining the rep of the old account, so signed up for a new one with a more permanent email. Confusingly, somewhere down the line — I think due to StackExchange not properly logging out — my new account now has my old account's rep, and my old account now seems to be able to login to this new one.

What I want to do is to prevent the old email address from logging into this account whatsoever. I've tried removing the old email address [as stated in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login), but if I then enter the old email address and password, it still seems to be able to log me into my new account.

This question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180631/i-remove-a-stackexchange-openid-login-but-it-still-links-to-my-account), but that one was unanswered.

Do I need to get an admin to delete the old account (I don't care whether the history associated with the old account is removed), or is there another solution?

Edit: I've now contacted support directly, so hopefully they will give me a solution. And now they have; all fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened was that your accounts were identified as both belonging to you and merged. It is no longer possible to delete the "old" account, since it's now one and the same as your "new" account.

I removed the disposable credentials from your account and we deleted the Stack Exchange OpenID associated with that disposable address, so you should be all set.

Comment: So the answer is that a dev/admin needs to remove the log in manually and there is no way for a user to do this by himself, not even in 2021 (or has something changed)?

Comment: @bugybunny A user can remove credentials on their own by going to `/users/mylogins/current` (e.g. `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current`) while logged in. This page is accessible in the UI by clicking "Edit profile and settings" and then "My logins" in the user profile.

Comment: My question was for the original question about deleting stored email addresses entirely. I have used <old email> and switched to <new email>. I have removed the old login at the site that you have linked and the new one is also working. But when I try to login again with <old email> and my password it says "You are about to create a new account …" I want to completely delete <old email> from Stack Exchange so I will just get a email/password is incorrect. And my first comment was asking if there is a way to do so by myself or if the support still has to remove that as was done for OP.

Comment: @bugybunny Ah, gotcha. Yeah, please reach out to support for that.